SQLAlchemy and proxy_association giving use default_factory error
So I am doing some learning, and I have followed several tutorials online for Flask-SQLAlchemy and dataclasses in Python. I have my app set up as bog standard as I can get:
__init__.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://log:pass@localhost/db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
CORS(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

I got up to a point where I am using the Object Association Pattern for Many-To-Many relationships, and that worked fine, returning what I need. I now want to pull an extra column from the middle table in that relationship, x. That led me to using association_proxy. I seem to have followed the tutorials correctly that I can find, but when I start up flask, I keep getting the following:

ValueError: mutable default <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.AmbiguousAssociationProxyInstance'> for field x is not allowed: use default_factory

models.py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped

from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

from . import db


@dataclass
class Main(db.Model):
    __tablename__="main"
    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ones: Mapped[List[One]] = db.relationship("One", secondary="manys", overlaps="main")

@dataclass
class Many(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "manys"

    main_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("main.id"), primary_key=True)
    one_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("one.id"), primary_key=True)
    x = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

@dataclass
class One(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "ones"

    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name: str = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    other_id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    many_link = db.relationship("Many", backref="ones")
    many_x: Mapped[bool] = association_proxy("many_link", "x")



Am I doing anything explicitly wrong? Am I missing something?
If I add in default_factory=None to my proxy_association, I get

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Attribute 'x' on class <class 'api.model.One'> includes dataclasses argument(s): 'default_factory' but class does not specify SQLAlchemy native dataclass configuration.


If you want your models to be dataclasses, configure them with MappedAsDataclass as described here. Don't use the @dataclass decorator (it can be made to work, but it's more complicated to configure)

Thanks, I could go back to trying that again. Do you know if there is some sort of Mixin that will make MappedAsDataclass work along the lines of Main.query.all()?? That is currently how I am querying the models.

Solved by the following. Retains the ability to use Main.query.all() functionality. Thanks for the pointer, @snakecharmerb.
__init__.py
#Model Base Class
class Base(DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass):
    pass


app = Flask(__name__)
app.json = BetterJsonProvider(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://login:passwd@localhost/db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
CORS(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app, model_class=Base)

"Dataclasses" now look like this:
class Main(db.Model):
    __tablename__="main"
    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ones: Mapped[List[One]] = db.relationship("One", secondary="manys", overlaps="many,one")

class Many(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "manys"

    main_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("main.id"), primary_key=True)
    one_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("one.id"), primary_key=True)
    x = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

class One(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "ones"

    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name: str = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    other_id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    many_link = db.relationship("Many", backref="ones", uselist=False)
    many_x: Mapped[bool] = association_proxy("many_link", "x", default_factory=bool)

